# Converting from Array[String] to Seq[String] in Scala

Tags: scala

In the following Scala code I attempt to convert from a String that contains elements separated by "|" to a sequence `Seq[String]`. However the result is a WrappedArray of characters. How to make this work?

```
val array = "t1|t2".split("|")
println(array.toSeq)
```

results in:

```
WrappedArray(t, 1, |, t, 2)
```

What I need is:

```
Seq(t1,t2)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The below works. ie split by pipe character ('|') instead of pipe string ("|").
since `split("|")` calls [overloaded definition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) that takes an regex string where pipe is a meta-character. This gets you the incorrect result as shown in the question.

```
scala> "t1|t2".split('|').toSeq
res10: Seq[String] = WrappedArray(t1, t2)
```